# Rails relative link within project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails project on the domain `domain.com/my_project`. On the main page, i.e. the page `domain.com/my_project` itself, I have a link `<a href="second_page">`.

Instead of linking to `domain.com/my_project/second_page`, the link links to `domain.com/second_page`, which is incorrect. I don't understand why that is, and how should I fix it?

Comment: Try to make a link to the controller `link_to "2nd page", second_page_path`, it should link automatically to /my_project/second_page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment should have been an answer I think.

Try to make a link to the controller using **link_to** helper:

```
<%= link_to "2nd page", second_page_path %>
```

It should link automatically to `/my_project/second_page`.